# How to handle bootstrap 5 collapse in initial state

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-5

I have a card that collapses when clicked anywhere on the card div. I have handled the case where the card is expanded, and clicking on the button on the expanded state does not collapse the card. However, when the card is in its initial state, and the button is clicked, the card collapses. How can I prevent this behavior?

The following code works when the card is expanded or in its initial state. What condition should I use to modify it to prevent the card from collapsing when the button is clicked?

```js
if (
  event.target.parentElement.id === "org-expanded-card" ||
  event.target.parentElement.className === "org-whole-task" ||
  event.target.parentElement.className === "org-whole-meet"
) {
  console.log("entered org-whole-task");

  console.log(this.dataset.test, "DATAtest");
  var myCollapse = document.querySelector(`[data-s-collapse="${this.dataset.test}"]`);

  if (myCollapse.className.split(" ").includes("show")) {
    console.log("show entered");
    var bsCollapse = new bootstrap.Collapse(myCollapse, {
      toggle: true,
    });
  } else {
    var bsCollapse = new bootstrap.Collapse(myCollapse, {
      toggle: false,
    });
  }
  return false;
}
```

I have tried using `show.bs.collapse`, `shown`, `hide`, and `hidden` but have been unsuccessful. I have spent more than three days trying to solve this issue and would appreciate any help.